# Will changing a private derived class affect the ABI if I use only pointers to the base class?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've been recently reading about the PIMPL idiom in C++ and its advantages over abstract base classes. One of the main points for the PIMPL is that it preserves ABI if the implementation changes. I've seen many articles in the internet and even similar questions here in StackOverflow. However, I haven't been able to find the answer to the following question:

Let's say I have a base class `A` and an implementation(derived class) `B`. Now, external code receives `B` objects but only via pointers to the base class `A`(and they can only use whatever methods or data members are available in `A`). Now if I change the implementation of `B`, for example adding new private members, will this result in an ABI breakage? My logic tells me this shouldn't be the case, because the external code doesn't know anything about `B` and so changes in it shouldn't affect the external code at all.

Can someone tell me if I'm wrong and also explain why? Thank you in advance.

Edit: To clarify what I'm asking about: I have a program which contains the classes `A` and `B`(the second one derives from `A`, overrides virtual methods and adds new data members, all of them not part of the "API" class `A`) , and it dynamically loads external .so files(via `dlopen()/dlsym()`). The question is whether these libraries will need to be recompiled when `B` changes(the code from the shared libraries uses only `A`)

Comment: The only way that would break is if `B` overrides functions from `A` that manipulate your  `private` members of `B`. Or if overiding functions come to rely on the state of your new `private` variables.

Comment: When you say "external code", do you mean "dynamic linking"?

Comment: @J. Calleja   I've editted to add clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re right—after all, the code in question was compiled without *any* definition of `B` visible, so how could it be the wrong one?  Even if `B` inherits from multiple base classes (even multiple classes with virtual functions), the vtable(s) contain the information needed for any pointer adjustments.